# Is `/dev/tty7` not directly accessible to Ubuntu users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty, pts

On Ubuntu, `/dev/tty7` is the virtual console for desktop GUI.

Is the only way to access `/dev/tty7`  to use `chvt 7` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>?

Besides that, is `/dev/tty7` not directly accessible to Ubuntu users, but indirectly via other emulations of terminals built upon `/dev/tty7`?  For example, typing this in a xterm window doesn't give any output:

```
echo hello > /dev/tty7
```

but this will

```
echo hee > /dev/pts/n
```

Comment: You don't usually see the text terminal on tty7 since it has a display server running. If you kill the display server you should see an output.

Comment: Since 17.10 (?) tty1 is a login screen, tty2 is the desktop GUI and 3-6 are text consoles. Don't know what tty7 is for. Previously 1-6 were text and 7 was the GUI.

Comment: Why would emulated terminals be “built upon `/dev/tty7`”?

Comment: @StephenKitt look at how `/dev/pts/2` is built upon `/dev/tty7` in "the chain of interaction" at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229598/674. I am not sure what you think is correct.

Comment: That “chain of interactions” is rather inaccurate.

Comment: @StephenKitt do you mind pointing out what is inaccurate and what it should be?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405689/86440

Comment: @StephenKitt do you mean X server  communicates with the physical text terminal not indirectly via virtual console `/dev/tty7` but directly?

Comment: X doesn’t communicate with a text terminal, but yes, I mean X doesn’t interact with the user via `/dev/tty7` (or any other terminal device) but by managing the input and output devices directly.

Comment: @StephenKitt (1)  Is "a text terminal" not an "input and output device"?  (2) Since I am running Ubuntu on `/dev/tty7`,  I guess  `/dev/tty7`must be involved somehow between my terminal emulator window and my physical terminal (my display, keyboard, touchpad)?

Comment: (1) It’s rather difficult to output graphics on a text terminal. By input and output devices I meant the graphics device, keyboard, mouse etc. (2) Your guess is wrong. Also, you’re not running Ubuntu on `/dev/tty7`; you’re running X or Wayland on the seventh virtual console. `/dev/tty7`’s involvement is mostly limited to ensuring that nothing else can grab the seventh virtual console; input and output don’t go through it.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Thanks. Sorry I know it is already long."/dev/tty7’s involvement is mostly limited to ensuring that nothing else can grab the seventh virtual console". How does a device file ensure that?

Comment: The device file is used to set the session group’s controlling terminal (with the `TIOCSCTTY` `ioctl`). The kernel only allows one session group to be controlled by a given terminal (although it’s possible to steal a controlling terminal).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. What does   "running X or Wayland on the seventh virtual console" mean? I guess it means something different from "ensuring that nothing else can grab the seventh virtual console" and "input and output don’t go through it"?

Comment: You wrote “I am running Ubuntu on `/dev/tty7`”, to which I replied “you’re not running Ubuntu on `/dev/tty7`; you’re running X or Wayland on the seventh virtual console”. That’s all.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu releases before 17.10 Ubuntu has 6 virtual consoles tty1-tty6 which are accessed by the keyboard combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. To access the GUI from any virtual console press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Starting with Ubuntu 17.10, which allowed the user to select either Xorg or Wayland when logging in, the virtual consoles are accessed by the keyboard combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. To access the GUI from any virtual console press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

`/dev/tty` is the controlling tty of the current process, for any process that actually opens this special file. It isn't necessarily a virtual console. For example running the command `echo hello > /dev/tty` in the terminal returns `hello`, but running `sudo echo hello > /dev/tty0` to `sudo echo hello > /dev/tty7` returns an error message similar to `bash: /dev/tty0: Permission denied`

*getty, short for "get tty", is a Unix program running on a host computer that manages physical or virtual terminals (TTYs). When it detects a connection, it prompts for a username and runs the 'login' program to authenticate the user.*<sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_(Unix))</sup>  On most Debian systems tty7 is used by the X Window System, so if you want to add more getty's go ahead, but skip tty7 if you run X.

Comment: I think the reason `sudo echo hello > /dev/tty0` fails is not what you think it is. Also, Debian 9 and later behave like Ubuntu, with the login session on VC 1, and GUIs on VCs 2 and up.

Comment: I remember to run `echo hello > /dev/tty0`, you have to first `sudo su`. `sudo` isn't enough, although I don't know why and also want to know why.

Comment: See this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60649/674 "Login as root"

Comment: Just sudo isn't enough because the redirection is done by the shell before starting sudo, so it's done with the user's permissions only.